# Sleuth annotations with Spring Webflux gives CglibAopProxy warnings

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-sleuth, reactor-netty

I have a reactive application using Spring Webflux. I have used sleuth annotations like `@NewSpan` to create spans, but I am getting warning like

```
CglibAopProxy|Unable to proxy interface-implementing method 
[public final void reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(org.reactivestreams.Subscriber)] 
because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
```

I know `Flux.subscribe` is a final method so proxies are not generated correctly, but I can still see those spans on Zipkin.

I need to know what are the implications of this warning. And how can I avoid this?

Comment: Can you show how you're using the `@NewSpan` annotation?

Comment: I am annotating my method @NewSpan which returns back a Mono. I am keen to know if we can use these  annotations with Reactor?

Comment: Btw I am subscribing to this Mono in my service class using .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
.subscribe()

Comment: It should work, can you just paste to your question the actual code?